# Running trezorctl / python-trezor on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, mac, trezor

As I am not familiar with python I am currently having trouble getting `trezorctl` running. After installing pip and running `pip install trezor` from my admin account I get the following error message when calling `trezorctl` in my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/trezorctl", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('trezor==0.8.0a0', 'trezorctl')
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 748, in run_script
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1517, in run_script
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/trezor-0.8.0a0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/trezorctl", line 28, in <module>
    from trezorlib.client import TrezorClient, TrezorClientVerbose, CallException
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/trezor-0.8.0a0-py2.7.egg/trezorlib/client.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import messages_pb2 as proto
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/trezor-0.8.0a0-py2.7.egg/trezorlib/messages_pb2.py", line 8, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import enum_type_wrapper
```